# Angularjs Account-based Authorization check on state changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authorization

I haven't been able to find anything on this yet, so forgive me if this question has already been asked in some other form.

I'm using Angular-UI-Router as my preferred routing method with Ruby on Rails 4 as my backend API. I'm building an app that is user-based (as in there will be hundreds / thousands of users). Each user has their own account that houses their information and it can be edited. Each user already has an authentication_token that they receive when they log in that is generated server-side, stored in the database, and then stored client-side as a temporary cookie while logged in.

What I have done for account authorization is define whether a state requires an authorization check during the state resolve, and then if it does I check if the user's state ID param matches their user ID (set as a cookie) AND if their authentication_token (cookie) is identical to the authorization_token defined in the API. The code is below. I'm using the Restangular module to make the HTTP requests and this code is used in the app's top level "run" cycle (it's an init file).

What I'm wondering is whether or not this is a valid solution, what the potential drawbacks or security flaws may be, and if this is a bad idea, what is a more effective solution for account-based authorization within AngularJS?

Thanks in advance!

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, toState) {
    // Restrict access if authorization is required from state data ("authRequired" is defined in module config files as part of the state definitions)
    if (next.data.authRequired) {
        Auth.getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {

            // Validate the user's token by checking if the "auth_token" cookie matches the user's API auth_token
            var user_token = user.auth_token;
            var auth_token = $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
            var validateAuthToken = (function() {
                return (auth_token === user_token) ? true : false;
            })();

            // Validate the user's ID by checking if the "uid" cookie matches the ID of the state param that is being requested.
            var uid = $cookieStore.get('uid');
            var sid = parseInt(toState.id);
            var validateUserID = (function() {
                return (uid === sid) ? true : false;
            })();

            // If either validation is false, restrict access
            if (validateAuthToken && validateUserID === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (Auth.isLoggedIn() === true) {
                    // user is not allowed
                    $state.go('home');
                    alertService.showAlert(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized, 'alert-danger');
                } else {
                    // user is not logged in
                    $state.go('auth.login');
                    alertService.showAlert(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, 'alert-danger');
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

Comment: I store auth token in session and not operate cookie, each request by angular will auto send cookie in request header and backend can get user session and deal with it.

Comment: Sounds similar to what I'm doing with my backend. My primary concern is displaying the user's account data on the client side and keeping it secure so that users can't access each other's accounts even if they were to hack the client-side code.

Comment: Session in cookiestore or sessionstore in broswer is safe for the all encrypted I think. Just operate it at backend.